# Finding brokers to invest in US index funds that support iraq

Tags: index-fund, brokerage, broker, online-brokerage, foreign

I live in iraq and i would like to invest in US index funds.looking at the popular brokers like robinhood and vanguard they state that they don't support investing from my country.Googling for iraqi brokers returns results of iraqi brokers but they only deal with iraqi stocks.

Is there a public record for registered brokers that are allowed to deal in US stocks that someone can look at?
If not how can someone find such brokers.

Regards

Comment: I suspect the best way to get advice is to talk to others in Iraq who have dealt with this issue.

Comment: SAXO bank says no to Iraq, IB says no to Iraq, and Standard Bank in Isle of Man says no to Iraq. I think the investor should look for an Iraqi broker that offers international investing. Otherwise a company could be formed in a foreign country and then that company could have an account in the foreign country.